# change the name of the identifier user_id

Tags: mysql

How can I change the name of the identifier user_id?
variant does not work above.
or is there an option sql.

```
id|user_id|name
----------------------
15|  2    |testreg
----------------------
18|  1    |Cheburashka
----------------------
6 |  2    |testreg
----------------------
19|  1    |Cheburashka
----------------------
20|  1    |Cheburashka


public function eBL() {
    $link_ebl = $this->config->address."?view=editprofile";
    $user_id = $this->data["id"];
    $name = $this->data["login"];
    if ($name == "") return $this->returnMessage("EMPTY_FIELD", $link_ebl);
    $result = $this->article->setName($user_id, $name);
    if ($result) return $this->returnPageMessage("SUCCESS_LOGIN", $this->config->address."?view=message");
    else return $this->unknownError($link_ebl);
}

public function setName($user_id, $name){
    return $this->setFieldOnID("user_id", "name", $name);
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking? Do you want to change the schema or is this some mapping ability you have within some framework you are using?

Comment: изменить имя user_id идентификатора

Comment: which framework you are using?

Comment: update.there are limitations in the method setFildOnID (). Changes unique id.Vybrat line with user_id can not

Answer (score 0):

If you want change the column name you  should use an alter table  (assuming the column to change name is an INT)

```
ALTER TABLE your_table_name CHANGE user_id your_new_name INT;
```